# Updated ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 now get RubyGem error when start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, ubuntu-10.04

I had ruby 1.8.7 installed on ubuntu 10.04 on linode, and I was running rails 3.0.7 for my rails app.

I then install rvm and used rvm to install ruby 1.9.3.

I have set my default ruby to 1.9.3 (my original ruby was not installed using rvm). Now when I start my rails server I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:861:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)                                                                             
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:255:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1204:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

How can this be corrected? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Rails gem is not installed for your upgraded version of Ruby. Each Ruby environment (version) has its own set of gems. You will need to reinstall the Rails gem for this Ruby environment.